# Site menu looks good on all browsers on Windows but breaks on Mac OS

Tags: html, css, macos

I've never ran into this problem before.

The menu looks good on Windows, but it breaks in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Mac OS (saw this by using browsershots). I don't have access to a mac so I can't debug it properly. I think it might be cause by different letter spacing or size. Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: My first guess would be font family issues.  Editing the CSS to make a better selection if the prefered font is unavailable may be required.

Comment: The current font-family is "Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif". I thought that was a pretty safe bet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm viewing the site in firefox on a mac, and it looks like the div with id="wrapper" is not long enough to contain the menu.

Either increase div#wrapper to 960px:

```
#wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
width:980px;
}
```

or decrease size of menu font to 16px:

```
#mainMenu ul li a {
background:url("images/bk_menu.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
color:#175689;
display:inline-block;
font-size:16px;
height:30px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:16px 19px 0;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to keep the site under 960px so increasing it to 980 isn't an answer. Eventually I'll decrease the size of the font, if I don't find a different solution (the designer probably will want to keep the size as it is).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, it looks fine in Safari 4, unless you post a screenshot. But it might be that you have `<div id="top-links">` occurring twice: [[Invalid]Markup Validation of  clients.newblack.ro integra  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//clients.newblack.ro/integra/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.